# partition on id and rank by date in mysql

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to create mysql code for below desired output using ranking in mysql -

```
id  startdate   rank
1   1/1/2017    3
1   6/28/2017   2
1   08/28/2018  1
2   null        3   
2   3/3/2018    2
2   9/29/2018   1
```

Comment: What MySQL version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Just use multiple [Order By](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-order-by/) clauses. First, order the data based on `id` in Ascending order, and within that, order the data by `rank` in Descending order.

Try the following query:

```
SELECT id, startdate, rank 
FROM your_table 
ORDER BY id ASC, rank DESC
```